# RTL8822BE wifi not working UBUNTU 22.04 Lenovo Legion Y530 Laptop

Tags: wireless, 22.04, realtek

I have Lenovo Legion Y530 laptop with 120GB nvme SSD drive and 1TB hard disk. The SSD drive originally had Windows installed. I formatted the 120GB SSD drive and installed UBUNTU 22.04 LTS no dual boot only single OS.

WiFi is not working after installation completes (during installation steps also wifi was not shown).

I did all updates, upgrade, and nvidia drivers from 'Additional Drivers' option of software & Updates.

No Luck!!!. :(

I set the system to suspend and after some time. When the system is brought from suspend mode wifi magically started working.

I tried several solutions available in google and also tried installing different versions of Ubuntu, nothings works.

Realtek wifi adapter: ["lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3" command output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBgaZ.png)

RFKILL command output: ["rfkill list all"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6zjG.png)

dmesg command output: ["sudo dmesg | grep rtw"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COt73.png) - Here you can find the wifi is brought after coming out from suspend mode.

lsmod command output: ["lsmod | grep rtw"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5ntX.png)

I believe some setting has to be made during the startup of the system.
if any one known any solutions help me out!!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtw88_pci disable_aspm=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtw.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266359&p=2 Post #29.

Comment: I tried the commands, it does not work.
please see the output of rtw.conf file:
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/rtw.conf
options rtw88_pci disable_aspm=Y.

I still setting the system to suspend mode and bringing up the system for wifi to work. If i restart or power off wifi does not work.